# Monaco Editor Marks Trailing Whitespace As Difference

Tags: monaco-editor, visual-studio-monaco

In Monaco editor v0.45.0, When a difference is present at the end of the line, the trailing whitespace on the line is marked as difference.

This error started to happen after v0.43.0.

I tried the option "ignoreTrimWhitespace" but it gave the same result.

Please check the attached image. In image1 which uses v.0.45.0 the whole trailing line is marked as difference [image: Image1 - editor v0.45.0]
whereas in image2 which uses v0.43.0 only the difference text is colored.

[image: Image1 - editor v0.43.0]

Monaco Editor Playground Link:
https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html?source=v0.45.0#XQAAAAIbBQAAAAAAAABBqQkHQ5NjdMjwa-jY7SIQ9S7DNlzs5W-mwj0fe1ZCDRFc9ws9XQE0SJE1jc2VKxhaLFIw9vEWSxW3yscw7sLNaAEiAJM8XEuX7Os378jBGtVLkr6ryuhqvky-XZ9Sy0vyFSI1m9lYQpwqOsaKmhydYWIo-9hGbv_4wlPHIol1gXlyE-FggjI3kNdcw19f9yHegkUkzNwDjXwHZr6aoSbdnyyEWAclBcWUhIMq11JrllrOakARMz_8-jq2sUjuJNNWAd-_XZfk544MznS5AaO045wJFm8f22iZ3lNJCsd38LMLmJf2uFLz_coY-zpDLSih0ffXYB71VXzwfCgeHHm1SD3CkxJZkysWQZ7XFOMG4bUM83m28Axl3lop1_p_rjaoGdFeX2i-p9Q3rEZqFQYUgyT1p0W-CzLdZ1O_4X0tSC88c3u0SelVHI0ZivDrm8HDgvM6jXJxmGk7_H7NgFQq2jNy05IX0IfEsvbCSCBsvMItogAoggInl5zHWgBOpuyv7ajBHkOKt2iX7QA8G2VZfmctQ5ITNzCMI9feDc6JJQ2T5FBTBt-Us-_vq883aVKluVLYVxP0jEnXxsm8haEkxHXEM2VGLErnMvhSoEqHqzSbTHGpIABs7eDj2fWlKe3KsZ_1EOQd921Bz2xZntTDmKv8X232

Any idea how can I resolve this?